# .htaccess file can be deleted by ftp user?

Tags: .htaccess, plesk

Have created a .htaccess file from root with chmod permissons of 400.  It is placed in the user ftp directory with all the details I have entered in plesk for it.  However when I log in to the ftp as the user ie (ftp://www.ftpname.co.uk with username and password) and it goes to that directory and shows me that the .htaccess file is already there and uploaded by the root I can still delete it as the user.

This is very frustrating.  Any idea what I am doing wrong and to stop the .htaccess file being deleted by the ftp user?

Thanks

CP

Answer (score 0):

It's in proftpd FAQ http://www.proftpd.org/docs/faq/linked/faq-ch6.html#AEN677

Docs advice to use this directives as workaround:

http://www.proftpd.org/docs/directives/linked/config_ref_IgnoreHidden.html

http://www.proftpd.org/docs/directives/linked/config_ref_HideNoAccess.html

Another workaround it's immutable bit, but I definitely don't recommend to using it.